# WCF Unable to get json

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

I am experiencing issues getting json into my WCF REST service.

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IMyService

    <OperationContract()>
    <WebInvoke(Method:="POST",
    RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate:="notify",
    BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)>
    Sub Notify(message As String)

End Interface

...
      <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="IMyService" />
      </service>
      ...
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp  />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
...
```

When I POST to my service at http://localhost:64574/MyService.svc/notify with the payload:

{
    "Id" : "123456789",
    "Code" : "1",
    "ExId" : "123456789",
    "title" : "Title",
    "message" : "Sample Message"
}

I get the error below.

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'There was an error deserializing the object of type
>   System.String. End element 'root' from namespace '' expected. Found
>   element 'Id' from namespace ''.'. See server logs for more details.
>   The exception stack trace is:
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator
>   reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver
>   dataContractResolver) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, Boolean verifyObjectName) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.ReadObject(Message
>   message) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterDataContractMessageFormatter.ReadObject(Message
>   message) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.CompositeDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

EDIT:
Ideally I would like to get the raw json from the request body using OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage but it seems I can only get xml. When I use JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc) I get json but not the raw json I expect.

Comment: Have you tried BodyStyle WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped ?

Comment: Sorry, meant WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest

Comment: Yes, I tried that. WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest or WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped returns me "Sample Message". I need the whole json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [System.IO.Stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx) as parameter.

**Example:**

WCF Service Interface:

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IService1
  <OperationContract()>
  Sub NotifyStream(jsonStream As Stream)
End Interface
```

WCF Service Implementation:

```
Public Class Service1 Implements IService1
  Public Sub NotifyStream(jsonStream As Stream) Implements IService1.NotifyStream
        Dim jsonString = ""
        Using reader As New StreamReader(jsonStream, Encoding.UTF8)
            jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd
        End Using
        'Do something with jsonString'
  End Sub
End Class
```

WCF Client:

```
Dim client = New Service1Client
Dim jsonString = "{ 'Id' : '123456789', 'Code' : '1', 'ExId' : '123456789', 'title' : 'Title', 'message' : 'Sample Message' }"
Dim stream = New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString))
client.NotifyStream(stream)
```

**Documentation:**

- MSDN Article: [How to: Enable Streaming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010(v=vs.110).aspx)